# IOnic ios toolbar caught by the to area

Tags: javascript, ionic2

Am using ionic2 and have setup my toolbar by

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
<button ion-button menuToggle>
  <ion-icon style="color: white" name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
<ion-title float>Dashboard</ion-title>
  <button ion-button clear float-end>
      <ion-icon style="color: white" name="search"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <button ion-button clear>
      <ion-icon style="color: white" name="hamburger"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

THe above in ios produces

[image]

How can i brig the toolbar lower to avoid being hidden below the top  area of ios
The above works perfectly in android and windows platform

Comment: Is this actually on a device or in the emulator of Ionic Lab?

Comment: Else you can move the entire header with the `.header-ios` class, just add a `padding-top` but it might actually work out when you're running this on a real device